# Saving geography data type in sql

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, .net, geography

I'm trying to add data to a geography field in sql using c# asp. net.

When adding a POINt or LINESTRING I get no errors but when adding a POLYGON I'm getting the following error;

```
  Message: [DataConnection.HandleError]: Query: Proc_CSA_AssetUpdateLocation: caused exception: A .NET Framework error occurred during execution of user-defined routine or aggregate "geography": 
System.ArgumentException: 24200: The specified input does not represent a valid geography instance.
System.ArgumentException: 
at Microsoft.SqlServer.Types.SqlGeography.ConstructGeographyFromUserInput(GeoData g, Int32 srid)
at Microsoft.SqlServer.Types.SqlGeography.GeographyFromText(OpenGisType type, SqlChars taggedText, Int32 srid)
at Microsoft.SqlServer.Types.SqlGeography.Parse(SqlString s)
```

The data I'm passing is (for example);

```
POLYGON((54.40854093377361 -6.197662353515625, 54.422126065167866 -6.212425231933594, 54.43011521616425 -6.164703369140625, 54.41093863702367 -6.128997802734375, 54.40094728183984 -6.150970458984375, 54.40854093377361 -6.197662353515625))
```

stored proc:

```
@Name nvarchar(20),
    @ModifiedWhen DateTime,
    @itemGUID UniqueIdentifier,
    @GeoLocs nvarchar(max),
    @Type int

    -- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from
    -- interfering with SELECT statements.
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    -- Insert statements for procedure here
    UPDATE dbo.csa_AssetGeoData 
    Set ItemModifiedWhen = @ModifiedWhen,GeoCord = @GeoLocs,GeographyTypeItemID = @Type, Name = @Name
    WHERE ItemGUID = @itemGUID
```

Unfortunately no matter where I look I can not find a reason for the error in my data.

My question is what could be causing this error?

I can provide more info if necessary, Sorry if this is too vague (uninformative).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK I figured this out. It doesn't like when your polygon lines cross one another. Not sure why but it's saving uncrossed ones and not crossed.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to pass the string representation and parse it in the script, similar to this:

```
SET @g = geometry::Parse('POLYGON((1 3, 1 3, 1 3, 1 3))');
```

I've taken this line from the [MSDN Polygon](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb895267.aspx) page.

Comment: I tried that but that's geometry not geography and as such throws an error in sql;
Operand type clash: sys.geometry is incompatible with sys.geography

Comment: Actually, by assigning a `nvarchar(max)` value to a `geography`-typed column, you *are* causing a parse that fails and throws. That's what the exception stack says.

Comment: I thought that too but both:
POINT( -6.261348724365234 53.351268586147086)
and:
LINE(53.74221377343109 -8.3221435546875, 53.02139221293762 -8.0804443359375, 53.77468884583564 -7.6190185546875, 53.40298249424814 -6.8719482421875, 54.0335863352108 -7.2015380859375)
 work fine!

Answer (score 0):

According to this blog [Ring Orientation SQL Spatial](https://blog.falafel.com/ring-orientation-sql-spatial/) MSSQL is left-handed. There are many ways to check the validity of the feature. Here is an example

```
        if (polygon.MakeValidIfInvalid().EnvelopeAngle() > 90)
        {

            region.Shape = polygon.ReorientObject().Serialize().Value;
        }
        else
        {
            region.Shape = polygon.Serialize().Value;
        }
```

Serialize in [SQLGeography](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sqlserver.types.sqlgeography.aspx) Used for sending spatial data across the network. So it converts a  instance to bytes[] that can persisted in a database.